# CasperJs and PhatomJs installed but getting an error when trying to run

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying out CasperJs but keep getting the following error when I run the command `casperjs sample.js`

```
Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?
```

I installed both CasperJs and PhantomJs via homebrew.

I'm sure this is something simple but I can't figure it out from the other answers I've seen around.

Answer (score 0):

Your phantomjs is not on the path, try typing phantomjs in the console.  Most likely you will see that it is not found.  Makes sure you add phantom to the path variables and it should work fine.